# use a boto3 "resource" to get an s3 bucket?

Tags: boto3

Short Version:

is there a way to use an S3 "resource" to get an individual bucket?  I can list the buckets using `s3_resource.buckets.all()`, but I can't figure out a way to target the single bucket that I need.

Long version:

I'm trying to use an S3 bucket to hand off files between two organizations.  That seems to mean that I have to use STS and `assume_role` on  order to do cross-account access.  The bucket is owned by the "sender", and the "reciever" is trying to pull out of the bucket.

```py
import boto3

# open a session
sts_session = boto3.Session(<use receiver credentials>)
sts_client = sts_session.client('sts')

# assume the role to get temporary credentials
assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::...")
credentials = assumed_role['Credentials']

# get the resource
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key=credentials['AccessKeyId'], ....)

# this works...I can list ALL the buckets and filter out the one that I want, but that
# requires "ListAllMyBuckets" permissions in the policy, which is too loosey-goosey

for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    if bucket.name != 'the-one-i-want':
        continue

    for my_object in bucket.objects.all():
        print(my_object.key)
```

I've tried a few things, since boto3 "collections" are modeled after the Django ORM.

```
bucket = s3_resource.buckets.get(name="the-one-that-i-want")
```

does not work (no method named `get`)

```
for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.filter(name="the-one-that-i-want"):
```

will run, but `filter()` doesn't seem to do anything (I get all the buckets), and it still requires that `ListAllMyBuckets` permission

Is there a way to directly get the bucket by name?

**UPDATE:**

@oleksii-donoha gave me a great hint.  I had cobbled my code together from a bunch of examples, and didn't realize that I had everything.  So the correct answer seems to be

```py
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket("the-one-that-i-want")
for my_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_object.key)
```

Thank you Oleksii!

Comment: Have you seen this in boto3 doc? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha yes, but .....aaaaah!  Now I see it!